# The method or property expo-file-system.downloadAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am a newbie with react-native.
I am trying to add expo icons, and when the project is running on the device I get this error:

[Screenshot with logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeUO3.png)

```js
{
  "name": "TrackYourFitness",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^36.0.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I tried **yarn react-native link**, but it didn't work.

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have u got the solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

According to your error message, you are trying to call the method `downloadAsync` from the package `expo-file-system`.

This package is missing in your `package.json`.

To install it: run the following command:

```
expo install expo-file-system
```

But I don't think this is related to your problem, because you're talking about icons. Icons package is already included in Expo, so it will work.

For reference: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

Answer (score 0):

run

```
npm install react-native-unimodules
npx pod-install //for ios
```

made changes in your android file based on IOS and Android
see link
https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/

restart react-native again...

```
npm start
npx react-native run-android
```

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I have the same error as mentioned above, your solution here will not work, since it is already installed, i dont know what to do, react-native-paper icons wont show up